# split a list by a lambda function in python

Tags: python, list

Is there any version of `split` that works on generic list types? For example, in Haskell

```
Prelude> import Data.List.Split
Prelude Data.List.Split> splitWhen (==2) [1, 2, 3]
[[1],[3]]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope. But you can use `itertools.groupby()` to mimic it.

```
>>> [list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby([1, 2, 3], lambda x: x == 2) if not x[0]]
[[1], [3]]
```

Comment: nice, this gets rid of empty lists too, which is what I was looking for (Haskell splitWhen does not, so one would have to filter afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

One more solution:

```
output = [[]]
valueToSplit = 2
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 2]

for i, val in enumerate(data):
    if val == valueToSplit and i == len(data)-1:
        break
    output.append([]) if val == valueToSplit else output[-1].append(val)

print output # [[1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5]]
```

Comment: You could have just included an empty array on the end to show there is a trailing 2, although it is personal preference >>> "a b ".split(" ")
['a', 'b', '']
>>> "a b ".split()
['a', 'b']

Comment: @robert king - I agree with you, and initially it was so, but then i read that the @gatoatigrado asked to get rid of empty lists, that is why i have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an iterator and use `itertools.takewhile` to include all matching items and discard the delimiter:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = iter(l)
>>> [[_]+list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!=2, a)) for _ in a]
[[1], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

@TigerhawkT3 answer isn't flawlessly, but i can't add a comment

when  `l = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]`

output `[[1], [2], [2, 3, 4]]`

seem "wrong", but he inspired me

```
import itertools
l = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
a = iter(l)
output = [[_] + list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 2, a)) for _ in a if _ != 2]
```

output = `[[1], [3, 4], [123, 123]]`